# apache beam watching bucket for ever gets stucked

Tags: java, apache-beam

i am using Apache Beam to watch continuously a bucket:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

     PipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.create();
     Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);

     p.apply(TextIO.read()
                .from("gs://myshard/sourcerepo/*")
                .watchForNewFiles(
                    // Check for new files every 30 seconds
                    Duration.standardSeconds(30),
                    // Never stop checking for new files
                    Watch.Growth.<String>never())
                )
     .apply(FlatMapElements
                .into(TypeDescriptors.strings())
                .via((String word) -> Arrays.asList(word.split("[^\\p{L}]+"))))
     .apply(Filter.by((String word) -> !word.isEmpty()))
     .apply(Count.perElement())
     .apply(MapElements
                .into(TypeDescriptors.strings())
                .via((KV<String, Long> wordCount) -> wordCount.getKey() + ": " + wordCount.getValue()))
     .apply(TextIO.write().to("gs://myshard/destrepo/wordcounts.txt"));

     p.run().waitUntilFinish();
}
```

problem is that the pipeline do not go to any step after the first transformation (apply) which is watching the folder for ever. Maybe is trivial but i would really appreciate an help.